# How to convert this code based on lists to code based on numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, keras

I am working with the keras and there is always a from with a lists, so I guess that always everything has to be converted to the numpy array which are very illogical for me. I guess that it is associated with performance? I don't see any other reason? However my problem looks like shown below. I have to convert this part of code:

```
output_sentence = []
final_output_sentence = []

for key in row['o'].lower():

    temp_list = []

    if key in dictionary.keys():

        temp_list.append(dictionary[key])
        output_sentence.append(temp_list)

    else:

        dictionary[key] = len(dictionary)
        temp_list.append(dictionary[key])
        output_sentence.append(temp_list)

final_output_sentence.append(output_sentence)
```

to the code based on numpy arrays. I try in this way:

```
output_sentence = np.array([], dtype=int)
final_output_sentence = np.array([], dtype=int)

for key in row['o'].lower():

    temp_list = np.array([], dtype=int)

    if key in dictionary.keys():

        temp_list = np.append(temp_list, dictionary[key])

        output_sentence = np.append(output_sentence, temp_list)

    else:

        dictionary[key] = len(dictionary)
        temp_list = np.append(temp_list, dictionary[key])
        output_sentence = np.append(output_sentence, temp_list)

final_output_sentence = np.append(final_output_sentence, output_sentence)
```

however instead of this `[[[1], [2], [3], [2], [4]]]` I get this `[1 2 3 2 4]`. Any ideas how to solve this?

**UPDATE**

What do you think about solution shown below? Any tips for performance optimization?

```
output_sentence = []

for key in row['o'].lower():

    temp_list = []

    if key in dictionary.keys():

        temp_list.append(dictionary[key])
        output_sentence.append(temp_list)

    else:

        dictionary[key] = len(dictionary)
        temp_list.append(dictionary[key])
        output_sentence.append(temp_list)

final_output_sentence = np.array(output_sentence)

final_output_sentence = final_output_sentence.reshape(1, final_output_sentence.shape[0], 1)
```

Comment: Generally it is better to use lists and list `append`, and create an array with one call at the end.  `np.append` (and other versions of `np.concatenate`) are slower, and harder to apply correctly.

Comment: With a sample of `row` and `dictionary`, and the results from the list version, we might be able to suggest improvements.  Sometimes there are ways of replacing list operations with whole-array ones.  But replicating the list appends is not one of those.  Why are you appending to 2 lists, when you only have one iteration loop (on `key`)?

Comment: @hpaulj Do you mean this two lines `temp_list.append(dictionary[key])
        output_sentence.append(temp_list)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
output_sentence = []
for key in row['o'].lower():
    if key not in dictionary.keys():
        dictionary[key] = len(dictionary)
    output_sentence.append(dictionary[key])

final_output_sentence = np.array(output_sentence).reshape(1,-1,1)
```

- If the `key` does not exist in dictionary then add it with the next size
- Append the value corresponding corresponding to the key into `output_sentence`
- Finally, `output_sentence` is a list but since you want a 3D array, convert it into numpy array and reshape it.
- x.reshape(1,-1,1) => reshape x such that size of 0th axis is 1, size of 2nd axis is 1 and the size of 1st axis will be same a elements in x.

Comment: @NinoFiliu Done will make sure to do so from now on.